# Playframework 2.6 Java のDIのサンプルコードが記載されているサイトはありますでしょうか？

Tags: java, playframework

Playframework 2.6 Java のDIのサンプルコードが記載されているサイトはありますでしょうか？

表題にあるとおりです。
DIを学べるサイトを探しています。公式ドキュメントは英語でかつわかりづらかったり、サンプルはあっても2.6でなかったりScalaだったり。
使い方を理解できることが目的なので簡単なコードであると助かります。
2.6でなくても同じ仕様のバージョンであればいいです。英語でもシンプルでわかりやすければいいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://riptutorial.com/ja/playframework/example/20699/hello-world%E3%81%AE--hello-world-

これよさそう

2.5と2.6の変更点と移行方法
変更点
http://lab.astamuse.co.jp/entry/2017/08/16/114500
移行方法
https://qiita.com/nazoking@github/items/3b715a30657cf358a1fc